# How to make reusable scrollbars in Tkinter?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, scrollbar

I'd like to create an easy way to add scrollbars to any frame I like. So far, only one works. What's wrong with this script? What's a proper way to do this? I still only have a faint grasp of all the concepts hidden in this, sorry.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def data(parent):
    for i in range(50):
       tk.Label(parent,text=i).grid(row=i,column=0)
       tk.Label(parent,text="my text"+str(i)).grid(row=i,column=1)
       tk.Label(parent,text="..........").grid(row=i,column=2)

class ScrollBar():
    #def __init__(self, tk):
    #    self.canvas = tk.Canvas()

    def myfunction(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"), width=200, height=200)
        print("orig: ",self.canvas)

    def makeScrollBar(self, tk, parent):

        self.outerframe = tk.Frame(parent, relief="groove", width=50, height=100, bd=1)
        self.outerframe.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.outerframe)
        self.innerframe = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.myscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.outerframe, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar.set)

        self.myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")

        self.canvas.pack(side="left")
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.innerframe, anchor="nw")

        self.innerframe.bind("<Configure>", self.myfunction)
        print("orig: ",self.canvas)
        return self.innerframe

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("800x600+100+100")

scrollbargenerator = ScrollBar()
b = scrollbargenerator.makeScrollBar(tk, root)
c = scrollbargenerator.makeScrollBar(tk, root)
data(b)
data(c)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you manage to create your scrollbars. If you scroll your mouse over the first scrollbar it will actually scroll the canvas. The thumb does not appear (or do not move) because the scrollregion is never set for this canvas.

In fact, your use of classes and objects is broken. Your `Scrollbar` class is instantiated once and this only instance update its fields each time `makeScrollBar` is called. Thus in `myfunction` callback, `self.canvas` always refer to the lastly created canvas.

You can easily fix your code my using different scrollbar generators

```
scrollbargenerator = ScrollBar()
b = scrollbargenerator.makeScrollBar(tk, root)
scrollbargenerator = ScrollBar()
c = scrollbargenerator.makeScrollBar(tk, root)
```

or capturing the canvas in a closure

```
def myfunction(self, canvas):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"), width=200, height=200)

def makeScrollBar(self, tk, parent):
    #(...)
    self.innerframe.bind("<Configure>", (lambda canvas: (lambda event: self.myfunction(canvas)))(self.canvas))
```

or relying on the information already present in event

```
@staticmethod
def myfunction(event):
    event.widget.master.configure(scrollregion=event.widget.master.bbox("all"), width=200, height=200)
```